# Using R to mail merge a word document with text and image placeholders

Tags: r, r-markdown, mailmerge, officer

In Word, you can prepare your doc with a `Text_placeholder` and `Image_placeholder` and effectively do a mail merge which replaces the text (as in all mail merges) but also iteratively embeds images at the image placeholder.

Is there a way to efficiently do this in R (produce 1000+ word docs) - to iteratively replace text with rows of a dataframe, and images (either with a dataset of images like jpegs, or just a folder full of images)?

#### Explainer

If you had a folder full of jpegs for example, I imagine you could do something like the following (***note*** the image lines won't be right) - and it would be even better if I could **output the word documents into a single PDF** (1000 page PDF rather than 1000 word documents) but not sure if this is possible.

Below code would be 1 address at txt_placeholder and 1 image at img_placeholder per output doc

```
library(officer)
# define placeholders
txt_placeholder <- "Address"
img_placeholder <- "Map_placeholder"
# folder of images
map_image <- list.files(path_to_images)

# Iterate over the rows of the dataset
for (row in 1:nrow(mm_dataset)) {
  # Get the address
  address <- mm_dataset[row, "ADDRESS"]
  # Get the path to the image file for the address
  image_path <- map_image[row]
  # Load the Word document
  doc <- read_docx(path_to_letter)
  # Replace the text placeholder with the address
  doc <- body_replace_all_text(doc, txt_placeholder, as.character(address))
  # Insert the image in the image placeholder
  doc <- body_replace_all_text(doc, img_placeholder, image_path)
  # Save the Word document
  output_file <- file.path(path_to_output, paste0("output_", row, ".docx"))
  print(doc, target = output_file)
}
```

Comment: Rmarkdown may be a better tool for dinamically generated docx files.

Comment: I second the opinion about Rmarkdown. See a simple example: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_mail_merge.html